# Python: Sort list using substring

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, sorting

I am tying to sort a list of urls on the basis of a keyword. I have tried cmp and key argument, but none is working for me.

```
l = ['KFC/l1', 'KFC/l2', 'KFC/p1', 'KFC/p2']
def match_score(sentence):
    some_pos = sentence.find('p')
    text_pos = sentence.find('l')
    return abs(text_pos - some_pos)
images.sort(key = lambda x: match_score(x))
```

The above is not working while my expected result is, sort by 'p1'

```
['KFC/p1', 'KFC/p2', 'KFC/l1', 'KFC/l2']
```

Thanks

Comment: Why does `'p'` come before `'l'` ?

Answer (score 0):

If your key is always the last 2 characters in the pattern character-int, sorted reverse alphabetically, then by the int ascending, you could use this:

`sorted_l = sorted(l, key = lambda x: (x[-2], -int(x[-1])), reverse=True)`

which gives:

`['KFC/p1', 'KFC/p2', 'KFC/l1', 'KFC/l2']`

Comment: Actually p1 is the word. What if I need to match a word in a string? Like sort by 'prod1'e.g sorted list would be ['KFC/something_prod1', 'KFC/something_prod2', 'KFC/something_model1', 'KFC/something_model2', 'KFC/something_life1', 'KFC/something_life2'].

Comment: This isn't clear to me what you mean by "sort by prod1" when only 1 value has that in it? Do you mean you want to do a character sort based on everything after the underscore?

Comment: Additionally I think if you have a numeric part which you want sorted ascending (i.e. 1, 2, 3 etc.) and a character part you want sorted descending (i.e. p, m, l) you are going to need to split them, since the default is to sort from a-z and from negative to positive (e.g. -1 < 0 < 1) or vice versa, but you require one direction for numbers and another for letters.